Как получить самую высокую и низкую цену за период в strategy pine script?
Я использую скрипт strategy(). Например в indicator() я могу использовать ta.highest(300), но в своей первой стратегии это работает не так. Я рисую две линии Макс. и Мин, в итоге получается с десяток линий на разных ценах актива. Как мне найти максимальную и минимальную цену (подобие уровней поддержки и сопративления) в strategy()?

Положите эту часть кода в
if (barstate.islast)

чтобы он выполнялся только на последнем баре.
